Webform - add more columns to summission table at page "/user/3/submissions"
Using Webform Version: 6.3.0-alpha2 with Webform Demo: Application/Evaluation System on Drupal 10.3.10
How do I add more columns to submission table at /user/3/submissions

The options I selected at /admin/webform/manage/demo_application/settings/submissions below don't all show.

Thanks

After looking a bit at the code I don't think it's possible without custom code.
The class liable to the table is webform/src/WebformSubmissionListBuilder.php
In initialize() the code relevant is:
switch ($route_name) {
      // Display webform submissions which includes properties and elements.
      // @see /admin/structure/webform/manage/{webform}/results/submissions
      // @see /node/{node}/webform/results/submissions
      case "$base_route_name.webform.results_submissions":
       ...
        break;

      // Display all submissions.
      // @see /admin/structure/webform/submissions/manage
      case 'entity.webform_submission.collection':
        // Display only submission properties.
        // @see /admin/structure/webform/submissions/manage
        $this->columns = $webform_submission_storage->getSubmissionsColumns();
        break;

      // Display user's submissions. THIS IS OUR CASE
      // @see /user/{user}/submissions
      case 'entity.webform_submission.user':
        $this->columns = $webform_submission_storage->getUsersSubmissionsColumns();
        break;

      // Display user's submissions.
      // @see /webform/{webform}/submissions
      // @see /webform/{webform}/drafts
      // @see /node/{node}/webform/submissions
      // @see /node/{node}/webform/drafts
      case "$base_route_name.webform.user.drafts":
      case "$base_route_name.webform.user.submissions":
      default:
        $this->columns = $webform_submission_storage->getUserColumns($this->webform, $this->sourceEntity, $this->account, TRUE);
        break;
    }

webform/src/WebformSubmissionStorage::getUserColumns():
public function getUsersSubmissionsColumns() {
    // This functions without any param will return only the "admin" columns
    $columns = $this->getColumns(NULL, NULL, NULL, FALSE);
    // Unset columns.
    // Note: Displaying 'label' instead of 'serial' or 'sid'.
    unset(
      // Admin columns.
      $columns['sid'],
      $columns['serial'],
      $columns['uuid'],
      $columns['in_draft'],
      $columns['completed'],
      $columns['changed'],
      // User columns.
      $columns['sticky'],
      $columns['locked'],
      $columns['notes'],
      $columns['uid'],
      // References columns.
      $columns['webform_id'],
      $columns['entity'],
      // Operations.
      $columns['operations']
    );
    return $columns;
  }

Therefore, those columns, for that route are pretty hardcoded and immutables.
Probably the easiest and fastest solution is to create a custom view of "Webform submissions" with a contextual filter on the uid.
You'll need also the webform views module.
Please comment if you need more guidance on how build that view.
If for some reason, the view approach isn't doable, this sandbox project may be a good example on how override\decorate the WebformSubmissionListBuilder

Ok thank you. Have a nice day.
